# Octave show fraction when divide without calculating the value

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra

The calculation of 1/23 * [1 2 3] returns [0.041667   0.083333   0.125000].

I just want a display like [1/23  2/23  3/23]

Comment: Do you only want to affect how values are displayed, or do you also want to affect how values are stored and computed with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify `format rat`, to always display outputs as rational approximations (applies to both matlab and octave).

```
format rat
a = 1/23 * [1,2,3]
% a = 1/23       2/23       3/23
```

Or, you can use that "rat" or "rats" functions, to print (as strings) the rational approximations of a float array:

```
a = 1/23 * [1,2,3]
% a =    0.043478   0.086957   0.130435

rats(a)
% ans =  1/23       2/23       3/23
```

As Cris pointed out in the comments, this is simply a representational issue. The underlying floating-point representation of the result does not change. If you wish to work with fractions in a 'mathematical' sense, then you need to go about this a different way (possibly symbolic package, or dealing with numerators and denominators manually).

Comment: @LuisMendo ah, thanks Luis. I remember octave has a couple of extra formats, I thought from memory this was one of them. I'll edit the answer. :)